# While Deploying highcharts Export Server on Production server getting error while generating charts for Auto configuration failed

Tags: node.js, express, charts, highcharts

> Auto configuration failed 140718236727232:error:25066067:DSO support
> routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared
> library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libproviders.so): libproviders.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> 140718236727232:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not
> load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
> 140718236727232:error:0E07506E:configuration file
> routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading
> dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=providers, path=providers
> 140718236727232:error:0E076071:configuration file
> routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module
> name:conf_mod.c:222:module=providers

I was expecting for chart generation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some issue related to PhantomJS, there is an issue on the official repository that may be helpful: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15449

However, PhantomJS has recently stopped being developed and the author has archived the repository.

The latest version of the Export Server which is now in beta already uses Puppeteer, you can find it on a separate branch on the official repository: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/tree/enhancement/puppeteer-as-module